# Why am I not seeing the worker node in my cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kind

I'm running a cluster with kind - one worker node.

However when I do `kubectl get nodes` I can't see the node, but instead I see 'kind control plane' - which makes no sense to me, control plane is a node??

The worker node must be running, because I can do `kubectl exec --stdin --tty <name of the pod> /bin/sh` and see inside of the container that's running my app.

Is this some weird WSL2 interaction? Or I'm simply doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`control-plane` is just a name.  If you just run `kind create cluster`, its [default](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/configuration/#nodes) is to create a single-node cluster with the name `control-plane`.  From your description, everything is working properly.

One of kind's core features is the ability to run a "multi-node" cluster, but all locally in containers.  If you want to test your application's behavior if, for example, you drain its pods from a node, you can run a kind cluster with one control-plane node (running etcd, the API server, and other core Kubernetes processes) and three worker nodes; let the application start up, then `kubectl drain worker-1` and watch what happens.  The documentation also notes that this is useful if you're developing on Kubernetes itself and need a "multi-node" control plan to test HA support.